# IllegalArgumentException - Only <= 256 finite strings are supported

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting this error when indexing my data. After some research I found why this is happening, and that increasing the `max_token_length` so I did this, but I'm still getting the same error of `TokenStream expanded to 912 finite strings. Only <= 256 finite strings are supported`

Here is my analyzer settings:

```
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "shingle_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "max_token_length": 920,
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "shingle_filter", "asciifolding"],
                    "char_filter": ["html_strip"],
                    "type": "custom"
                },
                "html_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "max_token_length": 920,
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                    "char_filter": ["html_strip"],
                    "type": "custom"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "standard": {
                    "type": "standard"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "shingle_filter": {
                    "min_shingle_size": 2,
                    "max_shingle_size": 5,
                    "type": "shingle"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what I'm trying to insert:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/{id}
{
    "myField":{
        "input":"Abcdefghij kl Mnopqrstwx yz Abcdef g Hijklmno pq Rstwxy Zabc (DEF)",
        "weight":2,
        "payload":{
            "iD":"2786129"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the mapping for the `my_type` properties

```
"Suggestion": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "myField": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "shingle_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "shingle_analyzer",
            "max_input_length": 150,
            "payloads": true
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

I will appreciate any help or clue to solve this problem, thanks!

**EDIT:**
Corrected `analyzer` enclosing missing

Comment: Note that you're missing and enclosing `"analyzer": {...}` part in your index settings to wrap your custom analyzers. See the [structure of custom analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html), `analyzer`, `tokenizer` and `filter` all go inside the `analysis` structure.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for this, I just made a mistake when writing it, I actually have all of them enclosed in the `analyzer` setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, days ago I came around with a solution. I just remove the `max_token_length` property from my settings in the analyzer and decrease the `max_input_length` from the mapping in my field and that seems to solve my problem, but I'm honestly not sure why does this happened and why does this solved it. If anyone has and idea, please, feel free to share your knowledge :)

Comment: does the shingle analyzer make any difference to the suggestion results ?As far as I understand shingle analyzer should not affect the results coming back since completion suggestion works on the entire phrase. Also what did you set the `max_input_length` to ?

Comment: It make a difference when dealing with accents, when I tun a query for a data without the accent the field with just the completion type does not work, but when I add the shingle_analyzer, it does suggests wether the accent is present or not. I just lowered the `max_input_length` to 25 in my case, this mange to solve it.

Comment: i suspect the accent fix is due to asciifolding filter not `shingle-filter`. If you remove `shingle-filter` from the analyzer you should not have the 256 issue